# RecyclerView - Different view returned in onClick

Tags: android, view, onclick, android-recyclerview

My code uses a recyclerview and implements onClick on the various items in each item (card view) of list. One of those items is a share button. The view that is received in the onClick listener is then passed via a listener to a fragment.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(mListener != null) {
        if(v instanceof ImageButton && v.getTag().equals("share")) {
            mListener.onItemClick(v, TYPE_SHARE, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

In the listener implementation in the fragment, the root view (card view) of the passed view is obtained

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int type, int position) {
    if(type == TYPE_SHARE) {
        View r = view.getRootView()
        View u = r.findViewById(R.id.card_view);//this is the list item 
        File file = LayoutScreenshot.getScreenshot(u);
    }
}
```

and then a screen shot of that view is taken via canvas methods.

While all this is working, the problem is that the view returned in onClick is not necessarily the one on which the user clicked.

[image]

This image is for representation and my views are slightly longer occupying a good portion of the screen. If the user clicks on the share button in item 2 for example, the view returned is that of either item 1, 2 or 3 depending on which direction was the user scrolling in and the amount of the clicked view now currently visible.

Am I wrong in passing the "view" to the fragment and then work on it there? Could someone please provide some pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to not rely on the view passed by the adapter in the onClick listener. Instead use the LayoutManager method. I did this

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int type, int position) {
    if(type == TYPE_SHARE) {
        View r = mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(position);
        View u = r.findViewById(R.id.card_view);//this is the list item 
        File file = LayoutScreenshot.getScreenshot(u);
    }
}
```

So, I used

> View r = mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(position);

to get the view and now the views are as per the item clicked in the list.